# Angular to MVC Controller - Binding $scope.object to List<Object>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a Model with a List inside:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class DrivingLicenceCommon
    {
        [XmlAttribute("IdDrivingLicence")]
        public int IdDrivingLicence { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("IdUser")]
        public string IdUser { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Lastname")]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Firstname")]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("BirthData")]
        public string BirthData { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("BirthPlace")]
        public string BirthPlace { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("IssueDate")]
        public string IssueDate { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("ExpirationDate")]
        public string ExpirationDate { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("ReleasedBy")]
        public string ReleasedBy { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Number")]
        public string Number { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("IdCertification")]
        public int IdCertification { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("IsVerified")]
        public bool IsVerified { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("CreationDate")]
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("CertificationDescription")]
        public string CertificationDescription { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("DrivingLicenceCategoryModel")]
        public List<DrivingLicenceCategoryModel> DrivingLicenceCategoryModel { get; set; }

        public DrivingLicenceCommon()
        {
            this.IdDrivingLicence = 0;
            this.IdUser = string.Empty;
            this.Lastname = string.Empty;
            this.Firstname = string.Empty;
            this.BirthData = string.Empty;
            this.BirthPlace = string.Empty;
            this.IssueDate = string.Empty;
            this.ExpirationDate = string.Empty;
            this.ReleasedBy = string.Empty;
            this.Number = string.Empty;
            this.IdCertification = 0;
            this.IsVerified = false;
            this.CreationDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900");
            this.DrivingLicenceCategoryModel = new List<DrivingLicenceCategoryModel>();
        }
```

When i POST my Angular Object to MVC Controller my DrivingLicenceCommon is full but the List inside is empty.

I use this Call for the Action

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/Dashboards/DrivingLicence_Add',
    params: $scope.drivingLicenceCard,
    headers:
    {
        "RequestVerificationToken": getToken(),
    },
}).then(function (result) {
}, function (response) {
    // error handler
});
```

The JSON for $scope.drivingLicenceCard:

```
{ "DrivingLicenceCategoryModel": [ { "category": 1, "categoryDescription": "AM", "startDate": "2017-05-31T22:00:00.000Z", "endDate": "2017-05-31T22:00:00.000Z", "code": "1" }, { "startDate": "2017-05-31T22:00:00.000Z", "endDate": "2017-05-31T22:00:00.000Z", "category": 2, "categoryDescription": "A1", "code": "12" } ], "lastname": "1", "firstname": "2", "birthData": "3", "birthPlace": "4", "issueDate": "5", "expirationDate": "6", "releasedBy": "7", "number": "8" }
```

And the Controller Method is this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult DrivingLicence_Add(DrivingLicenceCommon drivingLicenceCommon)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace params to data keyword in your config block

Comment: No! With "Data" is completely empty. With "Params" only the list is empty.

For now the workaround is use $.ajax(post) with FromBody in the Controller!